# plotly no space between pie chart and legend

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, pie-chart

I'm using plotly and I ahave created pue chart. the problem is that it works on jupyter ntoebook but when I download the graph the legend is overlap with the chart.

This is the plot on jupyter notebook:
[image]

but when I download it it as png it looks like this:

[image]

as you can see the legend items have very long names, but i'm not sure that cause the problem. Is there any way to control the spacing between the chart to the legend?

Edit: code sample:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go


fig = px.pie(df, values='count', names='LC', title='Land cover')
fig.update_layout(title_x=0.48)

fig.show()
```

I have also tried to play with the location of the legend this way:

```
fig.update_layout(title_x=0.48,legend={"x" : 1.7, "y" : 1})
```

but as I said, in jupyter notebook it worls but  in the PNG is overlap just the same, even when X is equal to 3:
[image]

Comment: Code sample, please?

Comment: Can you provide your code or a similar code sample so we can try to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @vestland   I have just added, sorry for the delay

Comment: What [renderers](https://plotly.com/python/renderers/#builtin-renderers) are used both for displaying and exporting the image? My guess is that the interactive renderer used on Jupyter notebooks corrects element placement automagically. See [Plotly: static image export](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/) for additional info.